# pdftex version history changelog

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to find the version history of pdftex (or an abbreviated changelog listing at least the significant changes). This is purely out of curiosity, so no specific questions. I thought that the user manual had a pointer to the version history, but I can't find it there. [I can't hack pagerank algorithms to find answers to "seldom asked questions".]

Thanks in advance
Nath Rao

Answer (score 7):

The texlive sources pdftexdir directory has a ChangeLog covering all major changes to pdftex since 2004

https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/web2c/pdftexdir/ChangeLog